# REST post method receives null DTO object

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, dto

I using Spring boot for REST application, I am getting null as DTO object even though the JSON request seems to be correct. Could anyone suggest something.

### json from postman

```
   {
  "description": "Third questionnaire",
  "createdDate": "2022-06-23",
  "approvalStatus": "Approved",
  "questionnaireVersion": "V1",
  "isActive": false,
  "questionSet": [
    {
      "text": "Question text",
      "possibleAnswerSet": []
    }
  ]
}
```

### Controller post method is

```
@PostMapping(
        produces =    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE   ,
        consumes =    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public String createQuestionnaire(@RequestBody QuestionnaireDTORequest questionnaireDTORequest){
        Questionnaire questionnaire =  mapToQuestionnaire(questionnaireDTORequest);
        Questionnaire createdQuestionnaire = questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire(questionnaire);
        if(createdQuestionnaire != null)
            return "Questionnaire created successfully";
        else
            return "Questionnaire cannot be created";
    }
```

when I run in debug mode i get questionnaireDTORequest as null.

### QuestionnaireDTORequest

```
public class QuestionnaireDTORequest implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;

private String description;

private LocalDate createdDate;

private String approvalStatus;

private String questionnaireVersion;

private boolean isActive = false;

private Set<Question> questionSet = new HashSet<>();
```

}

Comment: have you checked if the API gets called with the right parameters ? Does the request parameters match what you posted from Postman ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR Add getters and setters to `QuestionnaireDTORequest`.

Also, that will only make the values null, not the `QuestionnaireDTORequest` object. Is that the case?

I ran:

```
  curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8081/' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '  {
  "description": "Third questionnaire",
  "createdDate": "2022-06-23",
  "approvalStatus": "Approved",
  "questionnaireVersion": "V1",
  "isActive": false,
  "questionSet": [
    {
      "text": "Question text"    }
  ]
}'
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(
            produces =    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE   ,
            consumes =    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public String createQuestionnaire(@RequestBody QuestionnaireDTORequest questionnaireDTORequest){

        if(questionnaireDTORequest != null)
            return "Questionnaire created successfully";
        else
            return "Questionnaire cannot be created";
    }
}
```

The model was the same only added Getters and Setters.